# Laravel 5.1 - Ajax error POST 500 when site is online

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5.1

I have a problem with my AJAX call on my laravel 5.1 website.

when I run the site locally it works without any problems. However when I run the site online I get an error

[image: error]

The link of the page is [image]

here's the code I use for the ajax function

```
$('.articleFavo').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var userid= $('input[name=userID]' ).val();
    var functionType = 'favorite';
    var articleid=$('input[name=articleId]').val();
    var token=$('input[name=_token]').val();

    $.ajaxSetup({headers : {'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}});

    $.ajax({
        url:articleid,
        type: "post",
        data:
        {
            'functionType': functionType,
            'user_id': userid,
            'article_id': articleid,
            '_token': token
        },
        success: function(){
            console.log(articleid);
            $('#favoriteBtn'+ articleid).css({display: 'none'})
            $('#unfavoriteBtn'+ articleid).fadeIn();
        }
    });
});
```

and here is my PHP code

```
    elseif($functionType == 'favorite')
    {
        $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $article_id = input::get('article_id');

        $results = DB::select("select *
                       from favorites
                       where user_id = $user_id AND article_id = $article_id");
        $articleDetails = DB::select("select *
                       from articles
                       where id = $article_id");

        if ($results == null){
            $favorite = new favorite();
            $favorite->user_id = $user_id;
            $favorite->article_id = $article_id;
            $favorite->save();

            $notification = new Notification();
            $notification->user_id = $articleDetails[0]->user_id;
            $notification->save();
        }else{
            echo "You already added this as a favorite!";
```

}
            }

Comment: The error is within your PHP code first debug that

Comment: @Uchiha I posted the PHP code, agian offline it works perfectly so I'm not sure what could be wrong

Comment: From where you are getting the token you are passing in the ajax call? Where is this input.

Comment: @Franco from the form (it's a hidden field) here's code I use to get the toekn, and locally it works (I can console.log it) var token=$('input[name=_token]').val();

Comment: That's really strange, I have never seen something like this before. I am looking at your code and seems all right to me. Did you have a different .htaccess file on your server? Are you addresing somenthin in a different way or you just have uploaded the file exactly as it is in  your local environment?

Comment: Check also if the 'PHP' version you are running locally is the same on your server!

Comment: Check also if the 'PHP' version you are running locally is the same  on your server